# Remove firebase hosting

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I use angular2-cli and angularfire2. I wanted to add github authentication but to do so I needed to add callback URL. Okay, I did it but when I tried to log in via Github I got a message that my page hasn't been deployed.

What I did? Well, I just type 
`firebase init`
`firebase deploy`

and since then I can't do anything on my site because of that annoying message:

```
Welcome to Firebase Hosting

You're seeing this because you've successfully setup Firebase Hosting. Now it's time to go build something extraordinary!

OPEN HOSTING DOCUMENTATION
```

I don't want to create any hosting. I wan't to go back, remove that, so when I type again `ng serve` I will see my page instead of that message. How to do that?

I tried typing "firebase hosting:disable" into cmd and though I've got a message that all is OK, i still get above message about hosting".

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with ember.js. The command firebase init adds a index.html to the public folder, which overrides the normal serving of node.js.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. Firebase init adds index.html file (didn't notice that earlier).

Comment: How to fix this ?

Comment: how to fix this?

Comment: Simply remove the index.html file created by Firebase (check the source code).

Answer (score -3):

Just go to Firebase Console -> Hosting -> dashboard and delete.